# /boot/wpa_config being copied with wrong permission

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero-w, permissions, wpa

I plug the micro SD into my MacBook. I then save a correct `/Volumes/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` with file permissions with 777 (default when creating files into the FAT partition). Then, when I move back the micro SD into the Pi and I boot, the file gets copied to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` but with a `600` file permission, when originally it was `644`. That way, when the Pi boots, I cannot SSH from outside. So I am stuck. I cannot specify network and connect to it without a keyboard and a monitor....

I am using raspbian stretch on a Pi Zero W.

Any workaround or ideas?

Comment: AFAIK permissions on wpa_suppicant are irrelevant for SSH. 600 seems to be normal for the file anyway. SSH on Rapbian is not active by default. Did you activate it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you asked is simple - FAT partitions DO NOT support permissions. Anything you set is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

While [Milliways' answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90134/19949) is correct in stating that `/boot` is a FAT partition and its file access permissions work quite different from unixoid filesystems that is not why `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` has `600` permission. That is in fact by design and by the way a perfectly valid permission setting for Raspbian Strech - and working WiFi (I am typing this while being remotely logged into a Pi Zero via WiFi and a `600` `wpa_supplicant.conf`).

But how come we know that its perms are `600` after Raspbian moving the file from `/boot/` to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/`? That is because it's explicitely in the code. `/etc/systemd/multi-user-target.wants/` has `raspberrypi-net-mods.service` that is doing the trick. It is moving the file and sets the permissions to `600`. Given that it contains your WiFi credentials in plain text it might be wise to not have `world` (i.e. `other`) read permissions on it.

This is the actual code:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/mv /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

... and some related further reading: [Creating /boot/ssh and /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf (for a headless setup) works, but how?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1239853#p1239853).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry, I thought it was the file permission but indeed even `600` does work with the original file. I am waiting another 40 to post the real problem I found...

Comment: Here it is the new question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90119/whats-wrong-with-this-wpa-suppplicant-conf-file