# What's wrong with this wpa_suppplicant.conf file?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, permissions, wpa

I have an original wpa_supplicant.conf file which I tried to add a new network. Both have same owner (`root`) and same permissions `644`. I just added one more network at the end (just for testing). However, when I try to boot with the modified one, it simply says no network activity, it shows a red flag in the wifi icon and cannot connect to any network. However, when I boot with the original file, everything works correct.

I am running raspbian stretch on Pi Zero W.

Any ideas???

Original file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="Fibertel WiFi187 2.4GHz"
    psk="XXXXXXX"
}

network={
    ssid="eero_douai"
    psk="XXXXXX"
    priority=1
}
```

Modified file that doesn't work:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="Fibertel WiFi187 2.4GHz"
    psk="XXXXXXX"
}

network={
    ssid="eero_douai"
    psk="XXXXXXXX"
    priority=1
}

network={
    ssid="zaraza"
    psk="test"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK...I realized the issue...As I was just testing the move from `/boot/` to `/etc/wpa_supplicant`.I added a dummy new network but the password was less than 8 characters and so that made `wpa_supplicant` to silently fail. The way I discover this was by running:

```
 sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And there it clearly said about password being wrong and needed to be at least 8 chars...