# What file instructs the wpa_supplicant.conf to move from boot partition?

Tags: boot

I want to change it to copy, rather than move.

OK, some googlefu suggests it's in this service `raspberrypi-net-mods.service`

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspberrypi-net-mods/blob/master/debian/raspberrypi-net-mods.service

An idea how to locate this once installed?

Stretch Lite 2019-04-08

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As *Dirk* and *Ghanima* stated in their answers, the service may be overwritten by future updates/upgrades of the system. But **systemd** has a mechanism to avoid this. You can use a **drop in file**. An update/upgrade will only modify the main service. The drop in file is not effected by it and will also modify the updated main service. You can simply create a drop in file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit raspberrypi-net-mods.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/bin/cp /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The first empty `ExecStart=` is important. It will suppress the original ExecStart in the main service.

Check the source of the whole service with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat raspberrypi-net-mods.service
```

You will find the drop in at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It's a service. In this case it's `raspberrypi-net-mods.service`.

`systemctl status raspberrypi-net-mods.service` will give status, including full path of the service file.
`systemctl cat raspberrypi-net-mods.service` will show path and contents.

Be aware that an update/upgrade could modify the service file in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As [Dirk's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98137/19949) pointed out the `raspberrypi-net-mods.service` is responsible for relocating `wpa_supplicant.conf`. It is located in `/etc/systemd/multi-user-target.wants/`.

This is the actual code ([see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/90135/19949)):

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/mv /boot/wpa_supplicant.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

You could change that `mv` to `cp` and the script would do what you want. However, as Dirk's answer already pointed out, any future updates/upgrades of the system might overwrite that file. See [Ingo's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98143/19949) how to avoid that.